# Analytic function integrated over a closed disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_0\in \mathbb C$ and let $f$ be an analytic function in the open domain that includes the closed disk $ z:|z-z_0|\leq R $.

Prove that (a) $$f(z_0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi} \int _0^{2\pi}f(z_0+Re^{i\theta})d\theta$$

(b) Use (a) to prove that if $f(r,\phi)=u(r,\phi)+iv(r,\phi)$ is analytic in the open domain that includes the unit closed disk, then:

$$u(0,0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}u(1 ,\theta)d\theta$$
and 
$$v(0,0)=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2 \pi}v(1 ,\theta)d\theta$$

I need some help with these two.

Comment: What have you managed to do so far ? What have you tried ?

Comment: I don't  understand this linear addition of $Re^{i\theta}$ and the integration over $\theta$. Should I write the function in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PART 1**:

Cauchy's Integral Formula states

$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$$

where $C$ is a circle centered at $z_0$.  Then, parameterize $z$ on $C$ as $z=z_0+Re^{i\theta}$ so that $dz=iRe^{i\theta}d\theta$ with $0<\theta < 2\pi$.

Thus,

$$f(z_0)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} f(z_0+Re^{i\theta})d\theta$$

as was to be shown.

---

**PART 2:**

Let $z_0=0$ and $R=1$ in PART 1.  Then,

$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta})d\theta$$

We also have $f(0)=u(0,0)+iv(0,0)$ and $f(e^{i\theta})=u(1,\theta)+iv(1,\theta)$.  Thus,

$$f(0)=u(0,0)+iv(0,0)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} (u(1,\theta)+iv(1,\theta))d\theta$$

whereupon equating real and imaginary parts yields

$u(0,0)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} u(1,\theta)d\theta$$

$$v(0,0)=\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_0^{2\pi} v(1,\theta)d\theta$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Thanks a lot. What abput part (b). Could you help me with it too?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  I added.